How to send authentication session id to django backend using fetch api?
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/card/{{ auction.slug }}/add/', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            }, 
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.json(); 
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            if (data.added === true) {
                saveBtn.innerHTML = 'Saved';
            } else {
                saveBtn.innerHTML = ' Save';
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Fetch request failed', error);
        });
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                if (cookie.startsWith(name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

I am sending request to django backend via fetch api. When I try to retrieve the request user,
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000184986CDE80>>.

it returns an error
Why django not authenticating using session id? Should I need to send request.user.id but if send that any user can make requests for other users I think. Or am I sending session id incorrectly to backend?
views.py
def add_to_card(request, slug):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        pass
        
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, slug=slug)
    user = request.user
    
    data = {'added': False}
    
    card, created = Card.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    card_item, created = CardItem.objects.get_or_create(card=card, auction=auction)
    
    if created:
        data['added'] = True
    else:
        card_item.delete()
    
    return JsonResponse(data)


Why are you setting 'Content-Type':'application/json' for a GET request that doesn't even contain a body?

Have you verified what your request actually sends yet, via your browser dev tools? Check if all the headers and cookies you expected to see there, are actually being transmitted.

Request header:
GET /card/test-image-auction/add/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,uz;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken: n5vQQvwJKO3kO1Y8twsscmxGAX81SjXe
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Response header:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 146600
Vary: origin, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Server: daphne

but why it is not sending cookies?

What cookies are actually set in the browser, and for which host names / IP addresses? Host: localhost:8000 Origin: 127.0.0.1:8000 - quite an ... "interesting" setup, I would say. Why is this not rather using the same host name, but different ports for the front- and backend?

i am sending requests from django templates. I want to do make add to card dynamicly
